# WP_Query: ordering by meta_value_num & comment_count

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to create create a query that sorts posts by both number of comments and meta_value_num. I can get it to work for one or the other, but not both together.

I have tried this:

```
'posts_per_page' => '3',
'meta_key' => 'crfp-average-rating',
'orderby' =>'comment_count meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
```

But it only orders by meta_value_num

Comment: Number of comments would be `meta_value_num`...What is `crfp-average-rating`?

Comment: crfp-average-rating is the name of a custom meta key from a plugin. It is needed to use with meta_value_num. This works correctly to bring in the right number data if I use it on it's own in a query.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the `orderby` parameters to `meta_value_num comment_count`?

Comment: Apparently I didn't try that, but it has worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you should switch the order of your `orderby` parameters. WordPress will treat the second parameter as the fallback:

```
'orderby' =>'meta_value_num comment_count',
```